# Replace Info Windows with full-screen modal window?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a Google Map (v3) setup and instead of in-map Info Windows (limited to boundaries of the map) I would like to use a full-screen modal window that will take up all of the area within the browser window.  This map is for a mobile application, so I need all the space I can get in the window that pops up.

If anyone has any knowledge on how to accomplish this, or could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a full screen modal, then it doesn't have to be attached to the map, so you can use this structure:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="modal"></div>

<script>
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
  //options
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(e) {
  //do something with div id="modal"
 });
</script>
```